# Why do I have three providers in my Vagrant file?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vagrant

I am learning Vagrant

```
 config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "sshfs"
  config.vm.box_version = '1611.01'
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 1024
  end

  config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
    v.vmx["memsize"] = "1024"
  end

  config.vm.provider "libvirt" do |libvirt|
    libvirt.memory = 1024
  end

  config.vm.define "vm1", primary: true do |pupdev|
    pupdev.vm.hostname = 'puppet-vm1'
```

Why I am having all of a three?Why is not Vitual Box sufficient?

Comment: What if you were running VMware Fusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those providers allow you and others to guide vagrant to the same behavior in different virtualization environments. If the Vagrantfile is only supporting Virtual Box, then you only **need** the one.

As a bonus, you can define memory size as a variable at the top. In this example, you can change the value in one place:

```
memToAllocate = 2048

config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "sshfs"
config.vm.box_version = '1611.01'
config.vm.box = "centos/7"

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.memory = memToAllocate
end

config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
  v.vmx["memsize"] = memToAllocate.to_s
end

config.vm.provider "libvirt" do |libvirt|
  libvirt.memory = memToAllocate
end
...
```